# truncating numbers

Tags: macros

I would like to truncate numbers in a table of mine such that numbers smaller than a threshold `T` are shown as `<T`. I thought the `siunitx` package had that functionality but I was wrong. I am sure this is a simple macro but I am new to macros in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

% threshold 0.001

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
input   & desired output \\
0.0009  & <0.001 \\
0.001   &  0.001 \\
0       & <0.001 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of the value of T?

Comment: Probably the `round-minimum` option does what you want: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-minimum = 0.1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S}
1.5 \\
0.9 \\
0.003\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`.

Comment: I have added data, but as I said, `siunitx` cannot help. The `round-minimum` only applies to values rounded to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `xparse` and `collcell`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \myminimum { m m }
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { #2 } < { #1 }
      { $<$#1 }
      { #2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{r>{\collectcell{\myminimum{0.001}}}r<{\endcollectcell}}
    input   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{desired output} \\
    0.0009  &  0.0009 \\
    0.001   &  0.001 \\
    0       &  0 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant of `\myminimum` that uses `\num` for the output and has an optional argument which is forwarded to `\num`.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \myminimum { O{} m m }
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { #3 } < { #2 }
      { \mode_if_math:TF { < } { $<$ } \num [{#1}] { #2 } }
      { \num [{#1}] { #3 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: excellent. Is there a low-budget version that I can use in-cell without defining a new column?

Comment: @bumblebee That would be `\myminimum{0.001}{0.0009}`. Don't you upvote when someone helps you? (talking about the answer, of course, not my comment)

Comment: @bumblebee Of course, if you don't want to repeat the threshold when using the macro, you can do, for instance, `\newcommand*{\myformat}{\myminimum{0.001}}` and then `\myformat{0.0009}`.

Comment: @frougon thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz At your service. :)

Comment: I noticed when inserting e.g., `\myminimum{0.24141423}` into my table, the rounding function does not work. Is it possible to take care of rounding inside the macro? I tried `{ round(#2,3) }` but this would not work. Apparently, I am really new to LaTeX macros.

Comment: @bumblebee are you using `siunitx` to typeset numbers in your document?

Comment: yes, but rounding does not work together with the macro.

Comment: @bumblebee see the new edit, with it you can use `\num` from `siunitx`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it using `\myminimum{3}{0.001}{0.24141423}` but it throws an error. Did I misunderstand the order of input arguments?

Comment: @bumblebee you'd have to use `\myminimum[round-precision=3,round-mode=places]{0.001}{0.24141423}`. The first argument is optional, so uses brackets, and matches the optional argument of `\num` from `siunitx`. Or you use `\sisetup` to control the formatting of every `\num` usage in your document (or in ranges thereof).